# Tag for mesoscopic physics?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm just wonder if a tag for [mesoscopic physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoscopic_physics) should be welcome? I guess so :-)

Enjoy up/down-voting for this forgotten topic :-)

Some examples found those days:

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128054/
- [Regimes of Josephson junction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127972/)

and all the questions about Josephson junctions actually are questions about mesoscopic. I nevertheless think a tag "Josephson" would be too restrictive. Also, questions about superconducting qubits, nano-devices in general, transport problems in [topological insulator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-insulators) and so on, ... are all eligible as "mesoscopic" I guess.

Comment: Do you have any examples in mind of questions that need it? I don't think anyone really minds creating a new tag when one is needed, but it's better if we can see that existing tags don't cover it.

Comment: @DavidZ Done as an edit. Thanks for your comments. That's true I like to receive some alerts from the new questions in specific tag instead of parsing the site daily, so maybe it is an ego-centric affair to ask for a new tag that I like ... :-)

Comment: Nah, it's no problem to ask. In fact, tag creation is not a big deal - in many cases you don't need to ask on meta about it, you can just make the tag. But on the other hand we don't want _too_ many tags. Ideally they should only be created when there's no existing tag or combination of tags that serves the same purpose.

Comment: Mesoscopic physics (which is a sub-discipline of [tag:condensed-matter]) seems to be partially covered by the [tag:nanoscience] tag.

Comment: @Qmechanic People who do mesoscale stuff are likely to come after you with torches and pitchforks for that. They generally contend that the field is much bigger and more diverse than that.

Comment: FraSchelle, Why don't you suggest a tag name and wiki except.

Comment: Well, this was not meant as an accurate description, but a compromise in order not to introduce too many tags. Since the [discrete topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) rules in tag space, it is often better to compromise on a few common "umbrella" tags. If people wants a [tag:mesoscopic-physics] tag, go ahead. But note that there is still no guarantee that OPs are actually going to use it. A simple non-tag [search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mesoscopic) often does a more reliable/complete job.